# Какие из этих операторов выполняет не только арифметические операции?

Tags: javascript

1. *
2. -
3. +
4. %
5. /

Cо 2 и 3 вариантом понятно. Оператор "-" выполняет приведение типов string в number, что не является арифметической операцией. Оператор "+" выполняет арифметическую операцию сложения и выполняет конкатенацию строк. А остальные?

Comment: и где интересно сказано, что `-` выполняет такое приведение? прям вот такими словами, и почему тогда + не делает того же?

Comment: @teran в тестах js

Comment: @ruben `42 / '1'` ; `+"42"` ; `"42" * "1"` ...

Answer (score 1):

Оператор + помимо сложения чисел еще и конкатенирует (складывает) строку. Пример со строкой:

```js
console.log('Evgeny ' + 'Eremenko') // так ведет себя оператор + со строками
```

и с числом:

```js
console.log (2 + 1) // так ведет себя оператор + с числами
```

Comment: про "+" и "-" - это понятно, я спрашивал про остальные